# google mobile ads - using libgdx and Android studio

Tags: java, android, mobile, libgdx, ads

Ive got my whole game together, using libgdx, working in android studio, and now I'm in the process of putting ads into it. I've done the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) but it doesnt work when youre using libgdx(I cant just follow the steps).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I managed to get a banner ad to display.
What I did was follow [this](http://www.quagem.com/archives/642#more-642) spanish tutorial, with its accompanying [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cy8_8kB0Jc), but wherever you recognise pieces from the official tutorial i linked in my original question, use the official snippets. basically the part from the spanish/video tutorial that is needed is putting the game into a FragmentActiviy and making a layout file.